# Need a hand with this script to check service status

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

Sorry I am a beginner in programming. I encountered a problem that I cannot figure out to complete the script in a way I expected.

**Expected : This python script will identify a service [Webmin] is currently active or not then turn on the light corresponding to the GPIO.pinout.** 
*(If the service is active then the light will be on otherwise it'll be turned off)*

**Problem now: When I ran the script, the script will keep returning "active" in the command-line interface and the light wouldn't turn on. I tried to modify `os.system('systemctl is-active webmin')` to `os.system('systemctl is-active --quiet webmin')` to mute the output but the light still wouldn't work.**

Please help me to check whether if something is coded wrongly, I tried to Google it for similar information and solution but little did it helped me. Thank you in advance.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time

GREEN = 26
YELLOW = 19
RED = 13

# Pin Setup:
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(GREEN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(YELLOW, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RED, GPIO.OUT)


while True:

        check = os.system('systemctl is-active webmin')
        match = ('active')
        if check == match:
                GPIO.output(RED, True)
                time.sleep (1)

        else:
                GPIO.output(RED, False)
                GPIO.output(YELLOW, False)
                GPIO.output(GREEN, False)
```

Comment: What does `os.system('systemctl is-active webmin')` return?

Comment: It returns `active`

Comment: Have you checked if you really want to use BCM over BOARD? Regarding the output, instead of using True/False, have you tried 1/0?

Comment: @PauloPereira, Sorry, I'm a beginner, this is the first time i ever heard about GPIO board mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os.system()` only give you back the error code of the command, not the result of the command. As stated in [the documentation for `os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), you should look into using [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) for running OS commands and retrieving the results of them.

```py
import subprocess
check = subprocess.run(["systemctl", "is-active", "webmin"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if check.stdout == b"active":  # Your result may end in a newline: b"active\n"
    print("Webmin is active!")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! But something seems off with my Raspberry Pi. I copied your code and pasted it with ssh connection to my Pi. And I executed the script using `python 3 xx.py` command, but it returned nothing.

Comment: Did you try checking what result you're getting from the subprocess? `print(check.stdout)` after you run the subprocess, and if there's nothing there, then `print(check.stderr)` to make sure no error occurred when it ran

Comment: Okay, I followed your instruction and here's the output. [link](https://pastebin.com/gHQJg8gA)                                                                                                                                             This is an another output of the script [link](https://pastebin.com/i5Gg3RF4)

Comment: Alright, here's a follow-up. It seems that the output of `print(check.stdout)` is `b'active\n'`. The `if check.stdout == b"active":` must be `if check.stdout == b"active\n"` to work. I don't understand why is the absence of `\n` will be fatal. But still thank you very much @Oliver.R , if it wouldn't you, I wouldn't know about the subprocess module. Thanks!

Comment: The newline is necessary in our test as it is part of the output, and we're doing a direct comparison. You could make this `if b'active' in check.stdout:` to just test whether the output contains the word `active`, however this is potentially more error prone (for example, this would be true if your script returned "actively failed :("). Glad I could help!